# Formatting Value in View Layer

Tags: vue.js

Can someone please clarify this for me? How can I format a number in the view if the data is received from an API call (I can't format this on the back end).

For example, `let score = '0.929304045';`

In the template:

```
<div> {{ score }} </div>
```

If I add a computed function to do the formatting for me:

```
getScore(score) {
  return score.toFixed(2);
}
```

It gives me an error

> _vm.getScore is not a function

If I call `{{ getScore(score) }}` in the view.

Any clarity on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed values are not methods. They act like properties. This is not a case where you would want to use a computed value. Instead, make `getScore` a method.

```
methods:{
  getScore(score){
    return score.toFixed(2)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, define a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters).

Comment: Thank you kind sir. That was the problem using the computed route and not using it as a method.